# Stepping down voltage 120 VAC to either 110 VAC or 117 VAC

Tags: voltage

I'm a vintage radio collector and I have on my benchtop a Variac that I use for testing out radios.  I wonder if there's a way I can put together something that I can either put inside the radio chassis or in the cabinet area of the radio that would allow me to take the 120 V AC mains and drop it down to either 110 V AC or 117 V AC.

I know there are buck/boost transformers out there but nothing that seems to quite fit what am looking for.

They either allow for other types of voltage reduction that would not be applicable for these radios.

I estimate that the amperage would be probably at least one amp and maybe 1.5 when I turn up the volume on some of the sets. Usually the AA5 would draw probably less than one amp while the other larger vacuum tubes complement radios would probably draw more than 1 amp. I also have discovered that some vintage radio restorers use wire wound resistors that give off wattage and heat and I don't know how to calculate what I would need those resistors to be.

I appreciate any recommendations that may be sent my way.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to drop 120V to 117V (or 110V)? Most/all devices that run off of line voltage can tolerate a difference of a couple of volts...

Comment: I don't believe that is true when you are talking about radios that are 70+ years old.  Then a work from a short-term basis and provide good listening however, the transformers inside these old radios are not designed to handle the additional voltage.  Sometimes the vultures can Range from 120 to 126.5 V AC and that's just too high to subject these radios to the higher voltages.  I have An Atwater Kent radio that has a specific label on the back of the radio that says this is meant for 110 to 117 both AC.  I  have checked the radio forums and they recommend not running radios at high voltages.

Comment: Just a historical note for all the young'uns out there: Standard North American voltage was 110VAC in the 1930's.  It's crept up since then, because people are generally happier with brighter lights and more powerful motors and what not.  Since it's happened over decades, the "creep" in radios has been effected by older units aging out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, in general your radios should work OK at 120VAC.  Mains voltage has always varied, which is why the power company could get away with bumping it up over the years.

Second, you can install a filament transformer with the correct secondary current rating, set up to buck the AC.  It should be fairly small.  While you're observing all due safety precautions, also check that you're bucking the AC voltage, and not boosting it.  A 6V filament transformer should get you from 120V to 114V, which ought to be in the neighborhood you want.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuUNq4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you for the information and the schematic.  I have Heard from other vintage radio restorers that plugging in these vintage radios into 120 to 126 VAC will make them work for a while however, there transformers will end up failing because they're not Able to handle the higher voltage ratings.  My house has 126 VAC most of the time but sometimes it drops to 124 123 and that's still too high.  So I will investigate the diagram you put up above and I will look into finding the right transformer.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want to step it down more than 6V you can just use a higher voltage filament transformer and buck it down even more.

Comment: @joesradios What you have been told is incorrect. 110, 115, 117, 120, and 125 VAC are all essentially synonymous -- at the time these radios were made, line voltage was not tightly regulated. 10% or more variation from nominal values was not uncommon.

Comment: @duskwuff I'm pretty sure it still isn't uncommon.

Comment: They may very well have been voltage fluctuations over the years but that doesn't mean component life wasn't shortened. I know my Fisher 500c was specifically designed for 117 volts. When you bring that voltage up to my current 122-125 volts you change tube biases and tube life is shortened.
It's best to regulate your voltage to the manufacturers specs, that's the voltage the designers used when they created those circuits.

Comment: I have a German radio that 126vac runs the output tube plate voltage too high and makes the audio unusable. The 6vac secondary circuit above will give you 120vac (126vac - 6vac = 120vac (aprox) therefore 126vac - 12vac = 114vac (aprox) The above is based on your incoming voltage being 126vac. [Edited by a moderator.]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rob. The data sheets for tubes like 6D6, 6A7, and 75 all list 250VDC plate voltage as "Max". Using a VARIAC set for 110VAC into a 1935 Zenith radio the plates all measure either at, or very close to, 250VDC. The radio works well at 110VAC.

However, bumping the line voltage up to 120VAC does in-turn increase voltages beyond the tube's ratings. Here, too, the line transformer runs warm at 110. So it's a concern as to what to do in order to drop the line voltage going into the transformer so the radio doesn't fail prematurely and ruin the hours and hours of restoration work that I've put into it.

I had to order new higher power rated resistors for some of the biasing because they had failed in the radio. Those, too are running hot at 110. Not a great design, I'm thinking. But you see the importance of limiting the line voltage.